# Recommended Configuration for Azure Event Hubs in a Shared Staging/Production Environment

Tags: c#, .net, azure-eventhub, azure-appservice, azure-eventhub-client

I have two Azure AppService slots -- staging and production -- that are each pulling messages from the same Azure EventHub Instance.

When only one slot is active, everything works as expected.  However, if I have both slots active, they seem to compete for the same messages, and the state gets shared between the two slots unpredictably.  As a result, staging will have some messages, and production will have others.  This leads to unexpected and undesired behavior.

As an example, given messages `A`, `B`, and `C`, what currently appears to happen is:

Staging: `A`, `C`
Production: `B`

What I want is:

Staging: `A`, `B`, `C`
Production: `A`, `B`, `C`

How do I configure Azure Event Hubs to achieve the desired processing?  For additional context, I am using .NET/C# and the `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor` [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you are looking for a solution in which both slots process the same messages from an Event Hub? If so, your solution would be to use a different [Consumer Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#consumer-groups) per slot:

> [..] It enables multiple consuming applications to read the same streaming data in an event hub independently at their own pace with their offsets. [..]

Take a look at [this code example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor/samples/Sample04_ProcessingEvents.md#basic-event-processing) showing how to configure the processor to use a specific consumer group.

Comment: Thank you, Peter!  I was actually about to answer my own question as that is exactly what I ended up doing. :)  I appreciate you confirming that with your answer.